# android tcp/ip client using phonegap

Tags: android, tcp, webview, cordova

I am new to mobile development and I would like to write a TCP/IP client to run on android using phonegap, can anyone tell me where to start?

I was thinking of writing a class for this in java using the Android SDK and invoking it using javascript through the `_android.webkit.WebView.addJavascriptInterface(Object, String)_` method but I do not know if this is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at how to write phonegap plugins: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap-Plugins